# MELPA no longer works: error in process sentinel: End of file during parsing

Tags: package-repositories, proxy

MELPA no longer updates after no changes of mine. With a minimal .emacs of

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
(package-initialize)
```

the command `M-x package-list-packages` (`pa-l-`) fails with

> error in process sentinel: End of file during parsing

The proxy is set from environment variables: `url-proxy-services` is

```
(("https" . "127.0.0.1:8080") ("http" . "127.0.0.1:8080"))
```

How is this fixed?

Comment: Set `Options => Enter Debugger on Error` and reproduce the problem.  That will hopefully give you a backtrace that should help track down the origin of the problem.

Comment: This is most likely a truncated `archive-contents` file. Try `rm ~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/melpa/archive-contents`.

Comment: @wasamasa: also occurs on an empty `.emacs.d`